# How to get the truncated html text with ellipsis?

Tags: material-ui, ellipsis, testcomplete

When there were long string in the list showing in front end, we'd like to truncate it and end with "...".

Like:
"A list"
"item 1"
"item too looooooooooooooooooooooooong" => "item too loo..."
"item 2"

When QA trying to automate this feature, it seems it is not possible to get the truncated string with ellipsis(""item too loo..."").

[The html innerText is showing the full string rather than with ellipsis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5X57.png)

How could we get the truncated string with ellipsis so we could verify it in the automation test?

Thanks for any suggestions.

[The example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-night-i5060?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please include your code in your question

Comment: @Elitezen Please just click the "The example in codesandbox"